# How can I combine Doxygen and chmcmd in one target under CMake?

Tags: cmake, doxygen, chm

I want to make a .chm documentation with Cmake.
The relevant code fragment:

```
    set(doxyfile_in ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/documentation-config.doxygen.in)
    set(doxyfile ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile)

    configure_file(${doxyfile_in} ${doxyfile} @ONLY)

    add_custom_target(doc
        COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${doxyfile} 
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
        COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen"
        VERBATIM)

    add_custom_target(chm
    COMMAND chmcmd index.hhp
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/doc
        COMMENT "Generating API documentation with chmcmd"
        VERBATIM)
```

I.e. currently I define two targets. In this way `make doc` generates the html files, and after that `make chm` generates the .CHM file. It works OK, but needs some handwork.

Is it possible to combine them? (the working directories are different, so I do not see possible to use one more COMMAND in add_custom_target)
The ideal would be to chain the two targets.

BTW: chmcmd gives messages like

```
Error: Anchor Memory_8cpp.html#a1e349bf268cc8c667b3d264111b6a3c1 undefined; first use Memory_8cpp.html
```

I do have file Memory.cpp, so I guess that `chmcmd` wants to use a file, derived from my file. I am responsible for this, through not setting some option in `Doxygen`, or some version mismatch happens, or something else?

BTW2: Is the something line `FindChmcmd`?

Comment: You may mark target dependent from other (with `add_dependencies()`). So you need to call make with one of the target for build both. Or you may use `add_custom_command` instead of `add_custom_target`, and make one command *DEPEND* on *OUTPUT* of another.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, using the advices received here, I arrived at the config file below. Maybe it helps somone.

```
# ---[ Configuring  Doxygen and maybe chmcmd
if(NEED_DOCS)
  find_package(Doxygen)
  if(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
    message("Configuring ${PROJECT_NAME} HTML documentation")
    configure_file(${doxyfile_in} ${doxyfile} @ONLY)
    add_custom_target(doc
        DEPENDS ${PROJECT_NAME} # Make sure to up-to-date source files
        COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${doxyfile} 
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
        COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen"
        VERBATIM)
    if(UNIX)
      FIND_PROGRAM(DPKG_CHMCMD_FOUND chmcmd)
      if(DPKG_CHMCMD_FOUND)
        message("Configuring ${PROJECT_NAME} CHM documentation")
        add_custom_target(chm
            DEPENDS doc
        COMMAND chmcmd index.hhp
        COMMAND chmod 755 ${PROJECT_NAME}.chm
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/doc
            COMMENT "Generating API documentation with chmcmd using Doxygen output"
            VERBATIM)
        add_dependencies(chm doc)
      else()
        message(AUTHOR_WARNING "chmcmd is needed to build the .chm documentation.")
      endif(DPKG_CHMCMD_FOUND)
    endif(UNIX)
  else()
     message(AUTHOR_WARNING "Doxygen is needed to build the .html documentation.")
  endif(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
endif(NEED_DOCS)
```